# managing same micro-service with team

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, jhipster, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

We have one microservice which is divided into 4 modules. 
and 4 developers are working on each module respectively.

When we run instances on eureka, it will initiate with 4 instances and API gateway (load balancer) pick any instance in any of 4 and provide a response. in this case we are facing the problem, developer cant predicts response it coming from their developed code or any other code base(out of four). Is there a good way to handle this kind of situation?

I know, I can give the different name in a configuration for each developer, it will change the name of the instance and its solve problem, but is there any better solution for this.

Comment: Why are you not building the code of all four modules together and then deploy a single microservice?

Comment: It sounds like your local development environment is intertwined with other environments. You could try to go for full separate environments, additionally, you could change your code so that you don't rely on Eureka while developing.